# How to add active class in large image on click thumb image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

I've made a photo gallery by using jquery.

When I click on next, my image change according to index. But I want, when I also click on thumb (small image) image, then large image will be displayed according to that index. But I don't know how can I do this.

Please help me to solve this problem.

If possible, please give me full code clearly.

my one page code is:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#thumbs").find(".thumb:first").addClass("active");
  $("#large").find(".bigthumb:first").addClass("active");

  var getIndex = $("#thumbs").find(".active").index();

  $(".controls").each(function() {
    $(this).find(".next").click(function() {
      getIndex = $("#thumbs").find(".active").index();
      getIndex += 1;
      if (getIndex > ($("#thumbs").find(".thumb").length - 1)) {
        getIndex = 0;
      }
      setActiveImage(getIndex);
    });
    $(this).find(".prev").click(function() {
      getIndex -= 1;
      if (getIndex < 0) {
        getIndex = $("#thumbs").find(".thumb").length - 1;
      }
      setActiveImage(getIndex); //Set/Show Active Image
    });
  });

});

function setActiveImage(index) {
  if (typeof(index) == "undefined" || index == "" || index == null) index = 0;

  $("#thumbs").find(".thumb").removeClass("active");
  $("#thumbs").find(".thumb:eq(" + index + ")").addClass("active");
  $("#large").find(".bigthumb").removeClass("active");
  $("#large").find(".bigthumb:eq(" + index + ")").addClass("active");
}
```

```css
#thumbs {
  text-align: center;
  background: #77a5c6;
  padding: 5px;
}

.thumb {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#thumbs .active {
  border: 3px solid #333;
}

.controls {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.controls img {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0px;
}

.controls span {
  font-size: 13px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

#large {
  text-align: center;
}

#large .bigthumb {
  display: none;
}

#large .active {
  display: block;
}

#large .active img {
  border: 2px solid #333;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>

<div id="panel">
  <div class="controls">
    <i class="prev fa fa-hand-o-left"> Prev</i>
    <span>
          ---Thumbnail Navigation--- 
        </span>
    <i class="next fa fa-hand-o-left"> Next</i>
  </div>


  <div id="thumbs">
    <div class="thumb active">
      <img src="http://images.replacements.com/images/images5/china/C/lenox_china_garden_birds_no_box_P0000014675S0122T2.jpg" width="100" height="80" />
    </div>
    <div class="thumb">
      <img src="http://learnordie.files.wordpress.com/2012/05/thrasher.jpg" width="100" height="80" />
    </div>
    <div class="thumb">
      <img src="http://www.kevinhearne.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/pic6.jpg" width="100" height="80" />
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="controls" align="center" width="400px">
    <i class="prev fa fa-hand-o-left"> Prev</i>
    <span>
          ---Large Image Navigation--- 
        </span>
    <i class="next fa fa-hand-o-left"> Next</i>
  </div>


  <div id="large">
    <div class="bigthumb active">
      <img src="http://images.replacements.com/images/images5/china/C/lenox_china_garden_birds_no_box_P0000014675S0122T2.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="bigthumb">
      <img src="http://learnordie.files.wordpress.com/2012/05/thrasher.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="bigthumb">
      <img src="http://www.kevinhearne.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/pic6.jpg" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just a click event on `.thumb` and get its **index** using **[`.index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/)** and pass it to your `setActiveImage` function as below:

```
$("#thumbs .thumb").on('click',function(){
   var index=$(this).index();
   setActiveImage(index);
})
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/wn27ar9z/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

alternatively you can simply add `onclick` event to the tag definition, like i did in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ppynveo0/)

```
<img src="http://images.replacements.com/images/images5/china/C/lenox_china_garden_birds_no_box_P0000014675S0122T2.jpg" width="100" height="80" onclick="setActiveImage(0) "/>
```

Comment: @@Siddharth but when iamge url comes from database, then how to get parameter index setActiveImage(0) / setActiveImage(1) / setActiveImage(3)?

Comment: it can be easily done with the help of jsp or php, what is your query mate?

Comment: my query is like this : <div id="thumbs">
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM gallery_image") or die(mysql_error()); 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) { 
?>
<div class="thumb">
<img src="admin/uploads/thumbs/<?php echo  $row['image_name']; ?>" width="100" height="80" />
</div>
<?php
}
?>
</div>

Comment: I'm sorry.. please don't mind. I don't understand about mate. but I'm telling that, I'm using PHP, and my img url come from MySQL database... and I'm using while loop

Comment: <div id="thumbs"> <?php $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM gallery_image") or die(mysql_error()); while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) { ?> <div class="thumb"> 

<img src="admin/uploads/thumbs/<?php echo $row['image_name']; ?>" width="100" height="80" onclick="setActiveImage(<?php echo $_INDEX_OF_WHILE ?>)"/> </div> <?php } ?> 

</div>